# Настройка openVPN на raspberry pi (для telegram бота)

Tags: linux, telegram, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

Подключение к vpn создается, но соединения с серверами телеграма нет. На windows при использовании этого сервера vpn все ок работает
Вот вывод openVPN при старте:

```
Fri May 18 10:34:27 2018 DEPRECATED OPTION: --max-routes option ignored.The numb                                                                                        er of routes is unlimited as of version 2.4. This option will be removed in a fu                                                                                        ture version, please remove it from your configuration.
Fri May 18 10:34:27 2018 OpenVPN 2.4.0 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL                                                                                        )] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 18 2017
Fri May 18 10:34:27 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017, LZO 2.08
Enter Auth Username: freeopenvpn
Enter Auth Password: *********
Fri May 18 10:35:03 2018 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit                                                                                         message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri May 18 10:35:03 2018 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit                                                                                         message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri May 18 10:35:03 2018 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_I                                                                                        NET]62.141.41.5:19880
Fri May 18 10:35:03 2018 UDP link local: (not bound)
Fri May 18 10:35:03 2018 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]62.141.41.5:19880
Fri May 18 10:35:03 2018 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memo                                                                                        ry -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Fri May 18 10:35:03 2018 VERIFY OK: depth=1, O=5aafeb643984380b457c1edf, CN=5aaf                                                                                        eb643984380b457c1eef
Fri May 18 10:35:03 2018 Validating certificate key usage
Fri May 18 10:35:03 2018 ++ Certificate has key usage  00a0, expects 00a0
Fri May 18 10:35:03 2018 NOTE: --mute triggered...
Fri May 18 10:35:04 2018 6 variation(s) on previous 3 message(s) suppressed by -                                                                                        -mute
Fri May 18 10:35:04 2018 [5aafeb673984380b457c1efa] Peer Connection Initiated wi                                                                                        th [AF_INET]62.141.41.5:19880
Fri May 18 10:35:10 2018 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized                                                                                         with 128 bit key
Fri May 18 10:35:10 2018 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1'                                                                                         for HMAC authentication
Fri May 18 10:35:10 2018 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized                                                                                         with 128 bit key
Fri May 18 10:35:10 2018 NOTE: --mute triggered...
Fri May 18 10:35:10 2018 1 variation(s) on previous 3 message(s) suppressed by -                                                                                        -mute
Fri May 18 10:35:10 2018 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Fri May 18 10:35:10 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri May 18 10:35:10 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Fri May 18 10:35:10 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 192.168.231.158/24 broadcast                                                                                         192.168.231.255
Fri May 18 10:35:10 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

**ip a; ip r до включения VPN**

*ip a:*

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:f4:49:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:a1:1c:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.234/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9ec:be1d:87ea:1895/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

*ip r:*

```
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.43.234 metric 303 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.234 metric 303
```

**ip a; ip r после включения VPN**

*ip a:*

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:f4:49:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:a1:1c:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.234/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9ec:be1d:87ea:1895/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.231.151/24 brd 192.168.231.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::bd93:87ea:37e0:73c6/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

*ip r:*

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.231.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.43.234 metric 303 
62.141.41.5 via 192.168.43.1 dev wlan0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 192.168.231.1 dev tun0 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.234 metric 303 
192.168.231.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.231.151
```

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. приложите к тексту вопроса вывод `$ ip a; ip r` до и после запуска программы *openvpn*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin добавил вывод ip a, ip r

Comment: Не менялся dns сервер, исправил путем ручной установки dns